# Is there any GUI or Windowing system providing just a web browser?

Tags: browser, desktop, gui

I am looking for a GUI / Windowing System, or anything like that, which can be installed on a linux box, providing a web browser as the only User Interface.

For example, a GNOME like Desktop Environment with only a web browser launched on session startup, and nothing else installed. (no desktop, ...)

The idea is to build a very light HTML-based Desktop Environment on my box (like Synology's DSM, JoliOS, EyeOS), powered by a NodeJS server.

Any suggests are welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome OS is a good operating system with a web browser as the only real program. It does have other small features, but it is as close to just a web browser as it gets. It is google-chrome, so if you like mozilla or internet explorer, you're out of luck. I recommend getting Chromium OS as it is the open source alternative.

http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os